# Eclipse Mars with m2e can not change java compile path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, eclipse-mars

While trying to do a maven compile goal on a jar project in eclipse it failed stating that there was no java compiler found. It showed that it was using the path to jre1.8.0_45. My configured java build path in eclipse is using jdk1.7.0_80 and is configured for the correct corresponding environment.

I tried to rename the jre directory while eclipse was open but it showed that something had a lock on it, and sure enough it was eclipse that was launching with jre1.8. If I renamed the jre1.8 directory while eclipse was closed, then it would not launch again complaining that it cant find the java directory.

I guess what I'm getting at here is, is this a bug with Mars? Or am I missing something because everything in Eclipse is pointed to 1.7.

Thanks,
Nate

Comment: Eclipse uses its own Java compiler, it just needs a JRE.  It's independent of the Maven Compiler plugin's JDK path. You need to configure your Maven project's [pom](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html); not Eclipse, and not renaming directories. Look here for details:  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html

Answer (score 0):

You should point Eclipse to JDK installation.

Window -> Preferences -> Java\Installed JREs
click Add -> Select Standard VM, Next ->
and then in text box "JRE home" you should put path to JDK home,
it's quite misleading..

BTW you should specify java version in maven-compiler-plugin. M2E plugin will then recognize this settings and configure compiler appropriatelly

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/15/Telling-Eclipse-to-use-the-JDK-instead-of-JRE.aspx

Comment: Thanks! That was what I needed to do. I didn't have a full enough comprehension of maven's involvement with Eclipse project properties. It is all working fantastically now. Ant --> Maven is so nice

Answer (score 0):

It's the launch configuration of any m2e build that should point to a full JDK, cf. http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-choose_config_jre.htm?cp=1_3_5_2 (except you will be using a Maven Build configuration, rather than a Java Application).

For most other situations using a JRE should be perfectly fine.

Comment: I cant show any upvotes as my account is too new but thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong , but you should be able to mark right answer to your question 